# gdal_translate consuming too much memory when writing big JPEG2000 file

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, vrt, jpeg-2000

I am converting a 30.000 x 30.000 vrt image (made of JPEG2000 subimages) into a single (big) JPEG2000 image, using the KDU plugin.

```
gdal_translate -of JP2KAK -co QUALITY=100 my30000_3000.vrt myOutput.jp2
```

Now, my input is a 30.000 x 30.000 image, 4 bands, 8 bits per band. I would thus expect an average of 7GBi of RAM to be enough (let's add 1 GBi for "other processes"), but I would like to know if the conversion is possible with a limited amount of RAM, for instance, 4GBi.

I am trying to generate a 50k x 50k image with this method, but `gdal_translate` crashes after some time spent swapping bytes, keeping in mind I only have a limited amount of memory.

Is there a way to do so?

[EDIT] Versions : I am using gdal 2.2.2, with Kakadu 7.7[.1]

Comment: Does your GDAL have other JPEG2000 drivers installed? In which order they appear in the list if you do `gdalinfo --formats`?

Comment: I have access to the following drivers : JPEG, JP2KAK, JPIPKAK, JP2ECW, JPEG2000. Out of these, JPEG2000 (the NOT OpenJPEG verison) seems to make generation of lossless images a bit difficult, so I'd rather avoid that particular one.

Comment: Do they appear in that order in the list? What I suppose is that you run out of memory when reading JPEG2000 data, not when writing. If JP2KAK is first on the list it should be used but to be sure add `--config GDAL_SKIP JP2ECW,JPEG2000`. By adding also `--debug on` you may get more information about what happens in the process.

Comment: They appear in that order. I'll run the command as you suggest and return with feedback (somehow, I doubt the --debug is going to be usable at all). Many thanks !

Comment: After some tests, it appears the fact that the input images (referenced within the vrt) being compressed with JPEG2000 was extremely expensive. Converting them into GeoTiff reduced both the translation time AND the memory required.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what kind of JPEG2000 you have. If you have Kakadu utilities available you could open the image with kdu_show and use File-Properties tool. The first lines till Cblk are the interesting ones.